# Calling IDisposable Dispose Method of base Class in WPF from child class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, garbage-collection, idisposable

I am Working on a C# WPF Project which uses `IDisposable` Interface to Dispose Managed Objects like an `HwndSource` object that I will create on the constructor of `CompositionHost` class. I have seen several questions about `IDisposable` but none of them explains about this case.

#### The Problem

The Project is actually a Custom Control Library so the users can derive their own Window Classes from `AcrylicWindow` Class, So which would be the best place to call Dispose method.

If I was the one creating the object I Could have called the Dispose method by myself, but here the `AcrylicWindow` is created from an XAML file *(I mean the MainWindow.xaml,I have posted the code below)*.
Is it a good approach to call `Dispose(true)` of Derived Class by overriding `OnClosed` event of  the Window Class. Or will the Dispose Method get called automatically. Because I don't want to ask the user to call dispose method.

---

#### Sample Code

*CompositionHost.cs - **Base Class***

```
public class CompositionHost: Window, IDisposable {
    private bool disposed;

    public CompositionHost() {

    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (!disposed) {
            if (disposing) {
                // Releasing Managed Objects from Here
            }
            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

*AcrylicWindow.cs - **Child Class***

```
public class AcrylicWindow: CompositionHost {
    private bool disposed = false;

    public AcrylicWindow() {

    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (disposed) {
            return;
        }

        if (disposing) {
            // Dispose Managed Resources From Acrylic Window
        }

        disposed = true;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<fc:AcrylicWindow x:Class="Sample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:fc="clr-namespace:FluentCompositor;assembly=FluentCompositor"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</fc:AcrylicWindow>
```

Note: Here the `fc` Namespace Points to my Custom Control library.

*MainWindow.cs*

```
public partial class MainWindow: AcrylicWindow {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: No it is not calling dispose method, can i call dispose by overriding OnClosed method, Is it a good approach

Comment: Why does `CompositionHost` implement `IDisposable` in the first place? Is there any private field to be disposed?

Comment: yes it has a HwndSource that needs to be disposed, i mentioned it in the question